# Rest on your skills?

Tags: idioms

Is it possible to say "He doesn't rest on his skills", similar to "Rests on his laurels"?

The meaning of that phrase (presumably) is that someone is constantly learning and doesn't let himself be finally content and satisfied with his achievements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Rest on something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rest+on)***  is a phrasal verb and its figurative meaning is:

> 4. To rely, depend, or be contingent on someone or something.
>
>    - *You can't just rest upon the success of your first novel to remain relevant with readers, you have to always be striving for bigger and better things.*

Similarly, you could say that one shouldn’t rest on the skills they have learned so far but they must constantly improve their capabilities.

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: Wow, what a great answer. Thank you.